# The nameless horror

Tags: wordplay, story, anagram

> Long ago, we defeated the nameless horror that plagued our lands. We thought it was gone forever, but now ____. It's currently approaching our village roaring with ____ laugh, and witnesses say its appearance ____ than ever before...
>
> `SOLDIER A`: I heard that on the way here that thing terrorised a ____ monastery a few miles down the road, no doubt drawing some Catholic ____ in the process. She ____ and obviously severely shaken, but remains unharmed.
>
> `SOLDIER B`: They're telling us to pick up our spears and march against this beast, but the promised 10% ____ enough to make me just walk off into certain doom. I think ____ to wait this out and go into hiding. Oh and besides, they haven't even been able to provide everyone with horses for the fight! Look at this runt of a donkey I'm stuck with. They couldn't have found a ____ if they tried.
>
> `SOLDIER A`: You should have told me before. I could have got you a horse from one of the camp ____ when I was still in charge. Anyway, you flee if you like, I'm staying. Or you could stick around and watch ____ my sword into the creature's skull and rid the land of the monster once and for all.

Fill the blanks with different anagrams. (No partial solutions, please.)

Comment: are all of the blanks anagrams of each other or are they split up into smaller groups?

Comment: @juicifer All are anagrams of each other.

Comment: Great fun, this - a perfect work-break brainteaser :) Thanks!

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that A is tilting at windmills?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All of these anagrams make use of the letters:

> A, E, I, I, N, R, S, S, and T (9 in total).

The blanks can be filled as follows:

> Long ago, we defeated the nameless horror that plagued our lands. We thought it was gone forever, but now **IT’S ARISEN**. It's currently approaching our village roaring with **A SINISTER** laugh, and witnesses say its appearance **IS NASTIER** than ever before...
>
>  SOLDIER A: I heard that on the way here that thing terrorised a **SISTER IN A** monastery a few miles down the road, no doubt drawing some Catholic **SAINT’S IRE** in the process. She **IS IN TEARS** and obviously severely shaken, but remains unharmed.
>
>  SOLDIER B: They're telling us to pick up our spears and march against this beast, but the promised 10% **RAISE ISN’T** enough to make me just walk off into certain doom. I think **IT IS SANER** to wait this out and go into hiding. Oh and besides, they haven't even been able to provide everyone with horses for the fight! Look at this runt of a donkey I'm stuck with. They couldn't have found a **TINIER ASS** if they tried.
>
>  SOLDIER A: You should have told me before. I could have got you a horse from one of the camp **SITES I RAN** when I was still in charge. Anyway, you flee if you like, I'm staying. Or you could stick around and watch **AS I INSERT** my sword into the creature's skull and rid the land of the monster once and for all.

My 'in' was...

> 'the promised 10% RAISE ISN'T enough', followed shortly by 'a SISTER IN A monastery'.

PS Why this letter set? Perhaps the OP has something against:

> **SANITISER**! (Or has been eating **RAISINETS**?!)